# Prove or give a counterexample: $T$ is nilpotent $\iff$ $G(0,T)=V$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory, generalized-eigenvector

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $T$ is a linear map on $V$. $\ G(\lambda,T) $ denotes the generalized eigenspace of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda $. In other words, $G(\lambda,T)=\{v\in V\mid {(T-\lambda I)}^{k}v=0\text{ for some integer }k>0\}$.

Prove or give a counterexample: $\ $ $T$ is nilpotent $\iff$ $G(0,T)=V $ .

BTW: It is true when V is finite-dimensional.$\;$This can be seen from 8.18 in *Linear Algebra Done Right* 3rd Edition.

Any insights are much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not follow that $T$ is nilpotent in the infinite-dimensional case. Take the vector space with countable basis
$$
\{ e_1, e_2, \ldots\}
$$
and let $T$ be the left-shift operator that annihilates $e_1$ and sends $e_{i+1}$ to $e_i$. Then the generalized eigenspace (with eigenvalue $0$) for $T$ is all of $V$ since for any basis vector, there is a power of $T$ that eliminates it, but $T$ is not nilpotent since there is no power of $T$ that eliminates all the basis vectors at once.

Comment: Thanks for this quick and precise answer!

Comment: @SkysubO youre welcome! the left-shift operator is great for counterexamples when trying to move a linear algebra theorem from finite to infinite-dimensional, worth remembering for sure

Comment: Ahh, this is exactly what I need. Many thanks.